# How can I add bookmark icon on bookmarked page only at Pdfview?

Tags: java, android, pdf-viewer

I'm a beginner , and I use barteksc library to make pdf viewer, I can save bookmarkedpage and go to it by using SharedPreferences ,How can I add bookmark icon as ImageView on bookmarked page only.
 I use this code but the bookmarked icon appeared at all pdf pages.

```
  pdfView.fromAsset("sample.pdf")
                // .spacing(10)
                .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(page)
                /*.scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))*/
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                .spacing(10) // in dp
                .pages(arrayOfPages)//start from last page to support Right to left navigation
                .swipeHorizontal(true)
                .pageSnap(true)  //scroll through single pages like a ViewPager
                .autoSpacing(true) //scroll through single pages like a ViewPager
                .pageFling(true)  //scroll through single pages like a ViewPager
                .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onRender(new OnRenderListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInitiallyRendered(int nbPages) {
                        pdfView.fitToWidth(pdfView.getCurrentPage());
                    }
                })


                .load();


    }


}

//Menu Items
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
    return true;

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.save_bookmark) {
        int bookmarkedPage = pdfView.getCurrentPage();
        //TODO add save bookmark button
        //bookmarkedPage is the page which has bookmark
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(BOOKMARKS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("itemID", true);
        editor.putInt("bookmarkedPageNum", bookmarkedPage);
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Save bookMark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    if (id == R.id.goTo_bookmark) {

        //TODO load page saved in share preferance
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(BOOKMARKS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isBookmark = preferences.getBoolean("itemID", false);
        int bookmarkedPage = preferences.getInt("bookmarkedPageNum", 0);
        pdfView.jumpTo(bookmarkedPage, true);
        Toast.makeText(this, " bookMark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // the bookmarked icon

        if( bookmarkedPage == pdfView.getCurrentPage()) {
            bookmarkIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Is there  way to make bookmark icon appear at bookmarked page only?

Comment: Ok, I fully understood